# Qt 5 - почему Quit не работает?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

```
void Vesta::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    if (Initialized) 
        return;
    Initialized = true;

    SetDarkColorTheme();

    if (!StartApplicationGui())
    {
        QApplication::quit();
        return;
    }   
    StartApplicatonEngine();
}
```

На StartApplicationGui получаю ошибку(мою ошибку), по которой нужно закрыть приложение. Не закрывается.

Выход в слоте меню также сделан и тоже не работает, раньше работал. Что произошло?

Comment: Приложение умудрилось повесить не только себя, но и IDE Visual Studio 2013. Что-то она долго перезапускается... Что творится?

Comment: Мир жесток. Но может просто `QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed() == false`?

Comment: Всё нормально. Это он под отладчиком не срабатывает. Без отладчика все хорошо...